# Is there a Java equivalent to C#'s 'checked' keyword?

Tags: c#, java, casting

Yes, it's a trivial piece of code to write, but I still wonder if there's a built-in replacement.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Cast x to int, throw an exception if there's loss of information
 */
public static int safeLongToInt(long x)
{
  int result = (int) x;
  if (result != x)
    throw new RuntimeException("long doesn't fit in an int: " + x);

  return result;
}
```

The code in C# would be:

```
int foo;
long bar = ...;
checked
{
  foo = bar;
}
```

Comment: +1 because i've never actually need the 'checked' keyword before. Here is the MSDN ref incase anyone else is interested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Wow, there's actually a *keyword* for that in C#? Is this really something that you do so often that a keyword is in order?

Comment: More interestingly, there are both `checked` and `unchecked` keywords, and if neither is used, the default is set by compile option.

Comment: @Jeffrey: by compile option? That sounds like a terrible idea... are they at least context sensitive or can I never have a `boolean` flag called "checked" in my C# classes?

Comment: I'm sorry you think it is a terrible idea. We cannot please everyone I suppose. Your question, however, presupposes a falsehood. Yes, "checked" is a reserved word. It does not follow that you cannot have a flag called "checked". You can have a flag called "checked", or "for", or "class" or any other reserved word. You tell the compiler "I am using a reserved word as an identifier" by preceding it with @ in C#.  So "bool @checked;" is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (pre-release) open-source Guava library has the method you seek:

[Ints.checkedCast(long)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#checkedCast(long))

Answer (score 9):

No there's no equivalent, check out this [keyword chart](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html#keyword).

Answer (score 4):

No. Java doesn't have any automatic overflow or loss of information checking like C# does.